# how can I convert a string into number so i can use in an select statement?

Tags: php, sql, string

i want to have by the where clause an numberic id but i want it with a variable so i can select it easy.

i made a string and put the number in there and paste it in the select statement but it doesn't work because it seems like it isn't reading it as a number.

```
$sql = "SELECT ic.metatitle, im.name, ic.metadesc, ic.metakeywords FROM 
isacontent_content ic
INNER JOIN isacontent_module_anchorimage im ON im.contentid = 
ic.contentid 
WHERE ic.contentid ='". $idnr ."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
 if(is_array($result)){
    foreach ($result as $resItem){
        $metaData[] = $resItem->fetch_assoc();
        }
}
else{
    $metaData[] = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }


$defaultImage = "isadesign-default-anchor.png";
$title = $metaData[0]["metatitle"];
$image =$metaData[0]["name"];
$desc = $metaData[0]["metadesc"];
$keys =$metaData[0]["metakeywords"];
$img_str = "/anchor/images/";
$site_str = "https://";
$contentid =$metaData[0]["contentid"];
$_idnr = "12245";
$idnr = (int)$_idnr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The number is converted to string in your SQL in this line:

```
WHERE ic.contentid ='". $idnr ."'"
```

if you add single quotes around your number, the number will be interpreted as string by the SQL engine. You should remove the single-quotes and tell the SQL engine that you are assigning a number to that variable:

```
WHERE ic.contentid = ". $idnr
```

Comment: check your php_errors.log file for the detailed explanation. there might be some syntax errors in your code.